# how do I install snap on Ubuntu in terminal

Tags: snap

How do I install snap using the terminal?

I would like this questions answer to be as comprehensive as possible.

This is a very specific question, its not a duplicate!

I want to have an answer page that addresses installations on "all" versions of Ubuntu (a list of which can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history))

The purpose of this question is so that anyone that types the question above and forgets to add the version number will be directed to a response that covers all versions of Ubuntu.

I want the answer to address whether the person asking can(or can't) install snap on their version of Ubuntu, and if they can, the answer should provide terminal commands that they can copy and paste to achieve the intent of installing snap on their particular system.

If you want more information, just ask!

Comment: Which release of Ubuntu?

Comment: all versions as listed here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history

Comment: if it cant be installed on earlier versions of Ubuntu then I would like that it is also noted that is the case in the answer...

Comment: What do you mean by "ways other than installing via the terminal?" And why is the question so broad? The complete, authoritative instructions for installing snap in Ubuntu are at https://docs.snapcraft.io/core/install-ubuntu ...what more do you need?

Comment: Its not broad, it covers two things "snap" being installed on "Ubuntu", and is a one stop shop for people that ask that question conveniently in one place!

Comment: I edited the post and removed "ways other than installing via the terminal?" part as I think that part was a bit too broad, thanks for pointing that out...

Comment: Even before I edited the question, it was not even remotely a "Possible duplicate of" that link... How did you even make that connection?

Comment: It's an exact duplicate of this question and one answer to it covers all currently supported versions of Ubuntu. So there it is. That's how I made the connection. I searched for a comprehensive answer that covers all currently supported versions of Ubuntu. It's a coin toss between "exact" and "remote", so let the other reviewers decide.

Comment: how is it "an exact duplicate of this question" I am not only asking for installation on Ubuntu 16.04, I am asking a different question entirely!

Comment: It covers all currently supported versions of Ubuntu starting with Ubuntu 14.04, believe it or not, not just 16.04.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80919/discussion-between-chris-stone-and-karel).

Comment: Now that snaps are available on 14.04, the accepted answer will work for all supported versions of Ubuntu. We don't support end-of-life versions, so the rest are offtopic here.

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo apt-get install snap
```

should work unless it is not compatible with your version.

Comment: "snapd" is the package manager, package "snap" is a different tool, see https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/snap